# IE9 Compatibility view Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have problem with a website I am involved in development of when it is viewed in various older versions of IE including IE9 compatibility mode. I am not a Javascript developer so I need some advice on why this work in IE9 but not in compatibility mode. The following link is the best example.

http://www.hurdrolland.co.uk/architecture/

There is a javascript slider in place which you will see working in IE9 but when you switch to compatability mode is stops working completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply using `compatability mode` do this: Press F12 to open the developer window. Selected Documentmode to IE7 and in the tab under it select Script. Now refresh the site. You will see a couple of errors there.

I have Windows in Norwegian, and I am not sure how to translate this correctly into english. But it should help you to debug the problem.

By the way, try removing the last comma in the `images` string in `homeSlides`

```
var homeSlides = {
    html: '<h1>home</h1><p>Lorem ipsum...</p>',
    images: ['/media/17812/eastgate-cover.gif','/media/17873/ed-master-2.gif','/media/14233/cover-3.gif','/media/14241/cover-4.gif',]
```

}

To:

```
var homeSlides = {
    html: '<h1>home</h1><p>Lorem ipsum...</p>',
    images: ['/media/17812/eastgate-cover.gif','/media/17873/ed-master-2.gif','/media/14233/cover-3.gif','/media/14241/cover-4.gif']
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice, I have now removed the last comma but still seems to have the problem? Any other ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: You still have a few commas too much. Replace your pageSlides-array with this: http://pastebin.com/Wqnucdpi .

Comment: Thanks, these are being generated dynamically. When you say 'You still have a few commas too much' any chance you could highlight in the current live source where the extra comma is? I'll then remove that in the code. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Do you use json_encode? If you do, this should not be outputted wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I have isolated the extra commas in the output now and this is now working. Many thanks for your help on this.